# How large was the Babylonian Jewish community?

Tags: babylonian-exile, census

The Roman census of the year 48 CE, ordered by Emperor Claudius, reported 7 million Jews in the Roman Empire, which was 10% of the population.  Today, the best estimates place the number of Jews worldwide at 14 million.  So we have only doubled in 2000 years, while the rest of the world was multiplied by a factor of 40. (This was more the result of assimilation than of physical extermination.)

But outside the Roman Empire, there was a huge and flourishing Jewish community in Babylonia, which gave us many Sages and the Talmud Bavli.  But I could not find a reliable estimate of the size of that Jewish community.  I have heard the figure "one million" floated.  Is there anything in our Sources that gives us an idea of the size of Babylonian Jewry?

Comment: If there were public domains on Shabbat, as is implied in a number of gemaras, then accd to some there must have been at least 600000 [men] [on the streets] [daily].

Comment: I don't see how this is on-topic on this site (viz, about Judaism). Plus, you may get better answers at [history.se]. cc @dou

Comment: FWIW we have a tradition that less than 1/3 of Jews returned to Eretz Yisrael when allowed to do so and another tradition that the Jews of the Roman Empire were descended from that group. It may not be a good idea to "mix and match" these two traditions, but that does give you a ballpark figure